# Problema Ventana Modal Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, jquery-ui

Estoy utilizando jquery-ui para hacer el autocompletar de un input y al escoger el dato me cargue otros datos en otros input, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es el siguiente:

Cuando coloco el código del formulario fuera del modal funciona correctamente, pero al colocar el código dentro de la ventana modal ya no me funciona; es decir no auto-completa y por consiguiente no se pueden cargar los datos de los input.

A continuación el código que coloco fuera de la ventana modal.

```html
<div class="row">                                                                                   
<div class="col-md-6">                                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="document" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
 </div>   
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="nombr" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="apellid" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A continuación el código dentro de la venta modal.

```html
<div class="modal" id="nuevoUsu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>Nueva Apuesta</h4>                       
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="modal-body">

    <form action="registrar.php" method="GET" name="myform" id="myform">                                 
        <div class="row">                                                                                   
            <div class="col-md-6">                                        
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="document" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
             </div>   
        <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="nombr" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
                </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="apellid" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                               
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Cancelar</button>
    </form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Estoy utilizando estas librerías

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Script para donde llamo el archivo donde cargo los datos

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $("#document").autocomplete({
                source: "jugadores.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();
                    $('#document').val(ui.item.codigo);
     $('#document').val(ui.item.document);
     $('#nombr').val(ui.item.nombr);
     $('#apellid').val(ui.item.apellid);
     $('#id_jugador').val(ui.item.id_jugador);
        }
            });
  });
</script>
```

Archivo donde cargo el arreglo con los datos solicitados

```js
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
 # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "contabilidad");
 
$return_arr = array();
/* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
if ($con)
{
 $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jugador where documento like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
 
 /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
  $id_jugador=$row['id_jugador'];
  $row_array['value'] = $row['documento']." | ".$row['nombres']." ".$row['apellidos'];
  $row_array['id_jugador']=$row['id_jugador'];
  $row_array['document']=$row['documento'];
  $row_array['nombr']=$row['nombres'];
  $row_array['apellid']=$row['apellidos'];
  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Cierra la conexión. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
?>
```

Comment: Muestranos codigo de como cargas la modal

Comment: El código que coloque es el que utilizo para abrir el modal luego de dar clic en un botón

Comment: Actualicé la publicación, agregué más código. Funciona si coloco el código del formulario fuera de la venta modal, pero si lo coloco dentro no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logre dar solución a mi problema, era algo muy simple no estaba agregando el id del modal al javascript. La linea que agregué es la número 6 del siguiente código.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#document").autocomplete({
            source: "jugadores.php",
            minLength: 2,
            appendTo: "#nuevoUsu",  //Linea nueva, agrego el id del modal
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#document').val(ui.item.codigo);
                $('#document').val(ui.item.document);
                $('#nombr').val(ui.item.nombr);
                $('#apellid').val(ui.item.apellid);
                $('#id_jugador').val(ui.item.id_jugador);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```